# Necessity of irreducibility of polynomial over field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, ring-isomorphism

This is Problem no. 37 from 17th chapter from Gallian's Abstract Algebra text.

```
[Gallian Chapter 17 Problem 37][1]
```

Is it necessary that $p(x)$ should be irreducible over $F$. Obviously, $F[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ would not be a field. But will the set $\{a + \langle p(x) \rangle | a \in F\}$ be a subfield of the ring $F[x]/ \langle p(x) \rangle$.

The arguments I used to prove this problem is similar to argument Fraleigh used while proving Kronecker's Theorem, and the fact that $p(x)$ is irreducible was never used except to show that $F[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ is a field. So I think the result is true for any non-constant polynomial.

If I am wrong please give an counterexample and part where my arguments use the fact that $p(x)$ is irreducible.
This is the part of the proof from Fraleigh's text.
[Fraleigh's proof of Kronecker's Theorem][2]

Comment: Do you think that $\mathbb R[x]/(x+1)^2$ is a field?

Comment: No. Without irreducibility, it is not a field. But is there a field contained in $R[x] /(x+1)^2$ isomorphic to $R$

Comment: I think this is because the term "$X$ is a subfield of $Y$" is often used only when *both* $X,Y$ are fields. Here, if $p$ is not irreducible you still have that $\{a+\langle p\rangle\mid a\in F\}$ is a field and subring of $F[x]/\langle p\rangle$ but maybe one wouldn't use the term subfield